# Is it possible to add two labels inside an UIButton on Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have an `UIButton` on my `Swift` project and I would like to use a font-awesome icon combined with a text inside of it.

I know that I can set a title to the button but, as far I need that the icon and the text will be in a different text-size, I cannot combine them in the same title tag. I also have thought about to use an image (to set the font-awesome icon) with an attributed title but then I cannot change the color of the font-awesome icon.

I know that I can get this behaviour adding two labels inside an `UIView` but I would like to know if it is possible to get this on an `UIButton`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried `setAttributedTitle` with attributed string ?

Comment: @KetanParmar What do you mean with attributed string?

Comment: `NSAttributedString` can have different size/text/font/color in one string, try search on how to create it

Comment: @Tj3n Ok, thank you I am going to search now about it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set attributed title of your button with attribute string something like,

```
 let attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Click Here",
attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blueColor()])
button.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, forState: .Normal)
```

You can set multiple color,font,size for particular texts or part of string.

another example,

```
 attributedTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: @"Click Here", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)!])

   attributedTitle.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSRange(location:2,length:4))

  button.setAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, forState: .Normal)
```

So, you can specify location by using `NSRange` and can set different color and font attributes for specified range!

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for.